# Erasing cells in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, frontend

I'm making a game where you click on a chocolate piece and all the chocolate pieces in-between the directly above pieces, as well as to the right, of the piece disappear. (including the clicked piece)

For example, **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k53vE.jpg)** is what should happen if a piece is clicked.

(note: different rules apply to the green piece, if you click it then you lose and the game resets.)

My issue is that whenever a piece is clicked, I can't figure out how to get the squares, other than the clicked square, to 'disappear' as per the rules stated earlier.

Here is my pseudo code for how deleting the other pieces should work:

- Loop through the array comparing each item in the array to the clicked cells position.
- If the cell in the array is in the right spot (per the rules stated earlier) compared to the clicked cell, then delete it.

I've implemented the first step correctly, but I cannot seem to get step two working.

How should I approach deleting the cells as I showed in the image?

Here is the skeleton for step one:

```
 cellClick = function (cell) {
  var a,
    //get (x,y) coordinates from array tableData
    x = cell.pos.x,
    y = cell.pos.y;
  //make all cells above, to the right, and inbetween, fade appropriate cells
       for (a = 0; a < tableData.length; a++) {
        //check each element to see what it's (x,y) is compared to click cell, then delete.

       }
```

**[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzGOPK?editors=0010)** is my code in it's entirety.

Comment: just a hint, in edge, i see nul (literately)l, in chrome, i see nothing. the pictures don't load.

Comment: How is this game won? What's the objective? It's better to know what's going on and/or aware of what is expected. What are the parameters of this game?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Not sure why it's not loading for you, the only ES6 feature I'm using is 'let' which is supported by pretty much everything. But it's also not working for me on edge, chrome and firefox work fine on my end though.

Comment: The game is pretty simple, you take turns clicking pieces of chocolate with a friend (or against an AI), and the person who has to click the green piece loses! Simple as it gets, the game was designed to practice AI vs AI code. Not sure what you mean by the parameters, the game is limited to the 'chocolate' squares, and the cells are denoted by (x,y) as you can see in the 'maketable' function in my codepen

Comment: It's too simple, the first move can take out everything except for one row.

Comment: it looks like [Chomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomp).

Comment: @zer00ne , the AI vs AI implementation for which this is intended has increasingly larger and complex boards. However, for my implementation I'm starting simple.

Comment: @NinaScholz wow,  so that's where this came from! I had no idea, I learned this game as 'Chocolate Russian Roulette'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use an array with the states of the cells.

In this case I use an `X` and a space  for it, in real projects I would use `true` or `false` or some other state flags.

The function for setting a part off is running from the first line to the selected line and from the selected item  to the end of the row.

The aswer is in ES6, because the given link uses ES6.

```js
function setOff(y, x) {
    var i, j = 0;

    while (j <= y) {
        i = x;
        while (i < table[j].length) {
            table[j][i] = ' ';
            i++;
        }
        j++;
    }
}

var table = Array.apply(null, { length: 6 }).map(() =>
    Array(8).fill('X')
);

setOff(2, 6);

document.write('<pre>' + table.map(a => a.join('')).join('\n') + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I think next time I do a similar project I will use state flags as you suggested